# Executemany() SQL-Update Statement with variables for column names

Tags: python, hana

I am really struggling with updating many rows in python using SAP HANA as my database and PyHDB for establishing the interface between both applications. Its working when I "hardcode" the columns, but I need to dynamically switch the columns by defining them inside of an array for example.

I am able to update in a hardcoded way the necessary columns by performing the following SQL-query:

```
sql = """UPDATE "ARE"."EMPLOYEES" SET "LIKELIHOOD_NO" = %s, "LIKELIHOOD_YES"= %s, "CLASS" = %s WHERE "EmployeeNumber" = %s;"""
cursor.executemany(sql, list)
connection.commit()
```

What I want to achieve is the following scenario:

```
 dynamic_columns = ["LIKELIHOOD_NO", "LIKELIHOOD_Yes"]
 sql = """UPDATE "ARE"."EMPLOYEES" SET dynamic_column = %s, "LIKELIHOOD_YES" = %s, "CLASS" = %s WHERE "EmployeeNumber" = %s;"""
 cursor.executemany(sql, list)
 connection.commit()
```

I am always getting the error that the relevant column / columns could not be found, but I cant figure out a way to solve this.

Comment: Just format the string before you pass it to executemany. """UPDATE "ARE"."EMPLOYEES" SET {dynamic_column} = %s, "LIKELIHOOD_YES" = %s, "CLASS" = %s WHERE "EmployeeNumber" = %s;""".format(dynamic_column=dynamic_columns[0])

Comment: ufff.. time for a coffee. havent even thought about this, works fine!  thank you for that.

Comment: Glad to help. Passing sql and list of parameters is good for user input to avoid sql injection, but if you know what you are inserting into the query you can also use just format :-)

Comment: I dont get the full point of your statement, do you mean that your mentioned example is vulnerable for sql injection?

Comment: No, I mean that unless you format sql string with data from the user, you can use format on the sql string. In your case it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use normal string interpolation (`.format()`) to add the dynamic column name. You can see in the code [here](https://github.com/SAP/PyHDB/blob/826539d06b8bcef74fe755e7489b8a8255628f12/pyhdb/__init__.py#L24) that pyHDB supports "numeric" paramstyle:

```
for col in ['LIKELIHOOD_YES', 'LIKELIHOOD_NO']:
    sql = ('UPDATE "ARE"."EMPLOYEES" SET "{some_col}" = :1, "CLASS" = :2 '
           'WHERE "EmployeeNumber" = :3;').format(some_col=col)
    cursor.executemany(sql, list_of_tuples)
```

This code will run for both columns `'LIKELIHOOD_YES'` and `'LIKELIHOOD_NO'`. Adapt it as you need. It would work with a list of tuples like this:

```
list_of_tuples = [
    (value1, class_1, employee_no_1),
    (value2, class_2, employee_no_2),
    (value3, class_3, employee_no_3),
    (value4, class_4, employee_no_4),
]
```

The code in your question seems to be using the 'format' paramstyle instead, but that doesn't seem what pyHDB is using. [See PEP 249 for more information](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) on paramstyles.

Comment: thank you for that example. just one question to that particular term: SET "{some_col}" = :1 <-- the "1" means that it takes the first value of "list_of_tuples", correct?

Comment: @Alex it means first value from *each tuple* in the `list_of_tuples` - the query will run multiple times, one for each tuple.

Comment: the solution you have provided looks like a major boost in performance for me when updating the columns. at first it took around 6 seconds to update around 1500 columns, now its in the area of milliseconds. how is that possible?

Comment: @Alex that's the whole point of using parameterization and `executemany()` !!! It allows the database to cache the query plan and execute it with different arguments with no overhead.

Comment: brilliant. really brilliant. thank you for that point, it really keeps away a lot of headache!!